# Can't make gunicorn systemd service recognize change in code without rebooting my linux computer

Tags: django, unix-socket

I have deployed a simple Django app locally on my ubuntu machine using systemd.
I have created two files gunicorn.socket and gunicorn.service according to many tutorials on the web. When I change my app's python code, the only way to see the change on the browser is to reboot the computer.
I have tried doing different combination of the following commands without success:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart gunicorn.service
systemctl restart gunicorn.socket
```

I get the message:

```
Failed to restart gunicorn.service: Unit gunicorn.socket not found.
```

although the file gunicorn.socket exists as usual

Excerpt from my nginx config file:

```
    location /static/ {
        root /root/djdeploy/demo/static;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
```

my gunicorn.socket file:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

My gunicorn.service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=nad
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/nad/djdeploy/demo
ExecStart=/home/nad/djdeploy/venv/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          demo.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Is there a way to make the process faster, that is without rebooting the machine?

Comment: Where did you put the service file?

Comment: in /etc/systemd/system/